# Slack BoltJS on GCP Cloud Run doesn't trigger app.message

Tags: slack-api, google-cloud-run, slack-bolt

## Summary

I have a very simple BoltJS app deployed to a very simple GCP Cloud Run service, but I can't Slack to trigger the BoltJS app via sending a message to a Slack channel.

## Setup

Below is my setup.

### Code

#### Index.ts (bolt)

```
import { App } from "@slack/bolt";
import { config } from "dotenv";

// config dotenv
config();

const app = new App({
    token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
    signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET
});

// listen to all messages
app.message(/.+/, async ({ message, say }) => {
    console.log(`message: ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);
});

// Start your app
(async () => {
    await app.start(process.env.PORT || 3000);

    console.log("⚡️ Bolt app is running!");
})();
```

### GCP Cloud Run

I deploy my app to Cloud Run with a very standard Dockerfile.

### Slack Config

1. The **signing secret** from *Basic Information* is configured in GCP correctly
2. The **Bot User Auth Token** from *Install App* is configured in GCP correctly
3. The App is installed to the Workspace
4. **Enable Events** is switched ON in *Event Subscriptions*
5. The **Request URL** is configured as `https://<my-cloud-run-url>/slack/events`
6. **Subscribe to bot events** includes `message.channels`
7. ***ALL* Bot Token Scopes** have been added

## Results

When I deploy a new version of my app to Cloud Run, the deployment completes successfully.

In the LOGS for the Cloud Run service, I see the following, which is triggered by the iife that starts my app in `index.ts`:

```
⚡️ Bolt app is running!
```

### MAIN PROBLEM

If I type something in a public channel and hit `Enter`, I check the logs again, but nothing shows up.

I expect to see a log that shows the message that was just sent, but instead I see no logs.

Comment: UPDATE: If I enable sending DMs to the App, and then send the App a message directly, the message is processed. But NO messages to any channel except the DM channel to the App are triggering POST requests from Slack.

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

We were only able to get messages sent directly to the bot because we only subscribed to bot events. Subscribing to `message.channels` in the section *Subscribe to events on behalf of users* worked.

### Details

On the *Event Subscriptions* tab in app config, there are three sections at the bottom:

1. Subscribe to bot events
2. Subscribe to events on behalf of users
3. App unfurl domains

We subscribed to `message.channels` in #1, not #2.

Why did we choose #1?

Well, the description states: *Apps can subscribe to receive events the bot user has access to (like new messages in a channel).*

"new messages in a channel"... we were posting in a channel, but nothing happened. Apparently the bot user doesn't have access to new messages in public channels.

***Documentation could be improved.***